# Bar chart using c sharp

Tags: c#, mschart

i had developed a windows app, which is is giving ouput in 4 textboexs,now i want these 4 values in to a Bar Grapg in another window, i had download wd MS chart but not able to understanad how to use it to make a window which displays these texeboxes values into bar chat in 1 click

Answer (score 0):

Creating chart of any kind takes at least some amount of work. And it depends upon the charting library you are using. I would recommend [NPlot](http://netcontrols.org/) as it is free, small and very easy to work with.

Comment: Is NPlot easy to use ,and i'm woking in c # 3.5 will it work in it,if it works can i get some sapmles

Comment: Yes. I believe you can use the dll for .NET 2.0 with .NET 3.5. The examples page shows some quick ways to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Not real sure of the question but I would look at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart. There is plenty of documentation and even some sample code. 
I have used MsCharts for a previous project and found the examples rather sufficient.